# How was I suppose to handle this review?

Tags: support, declined-flags

I recently got my first declined flag on this now deleted [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30668883/how-to-find-the-difference-between-multiple-text-files) from the Triage review. While reviewing it I wasn't able to add a comment. I'm guessing because the question got removed in the middle of me reviewing it, so I decided to add a flag. But the only flag that I had available was the Moderator's Attention flag, which was declined with the message "declined - flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention".

I understand why it was declined but how else was I able to handle this review? Could I just clicked Skip since it was apparently deleted while being reviewed?

Comment: What was the problem that needed to be solved, and what did you say when you flagged the question?

Comment: If it was apparently deleted while you were reviewing, then Skip is a perfectly valid option. Really, anytime you aren't sure what to do or cannot take the action you wish to (For instance, unable to comment as the question has been deleted) Skip is completely appropriate.

Comment: @Servy I'm unable to view the deleted question but the person asking the question wanted us to give them Python code on how to find the difference between multiple text files without showing any effort in trying themselves. Maybe I should of chosen to Skip the review like Kendra said lol.

Comment: @JohnOdom If you think that the question didn't do sufficient research then you can downvote it.  Why do you think that merits flagging?  And again, what did you actually say in your flag?  What were you expecting the mod to do, and what did you ask them to do in your flag?

Comment: @Servy I know I could of downvoted. I guess seeing that the only flag I had available was moderator's attention threw me off. I could of handled that review better. I said this in the flag: "User asking for help on developing a python program without showing any effort in trying." This was only the first time I made this mistake though because usually I would add a comment asking the questioner to add code.

Comment: @JohnOdom Again, you're not actually answering all of my questions.  What did you expect the mod to do?  You think that they question didn't show enough effort; that doesn't necessitate any moderator action which is *exactly what the mod told you in the declination message*.

Comment: @Servy, Sorry, I didn't really think about that part of what I expected the mod to do since I was thinking more about what I'm suppose to do in that situation. Machavity has answered my question though which was to downvote the question or skip if I don't know what I'm suppose to do since the review limited me to only that flag and I lack the rep to cast close votes.

Comment: @JohnOdom Since you have no idea what you want the mod to do, You shouldn't be surprised that the mod declined the flag because they also didn't see anything for them to do.  You shouldn't just flag for moderator attention because you don't know what you should do.

Comment: @Servy I know, I wasn't surprised at all :). I just wanted to know how I could of handled it better since my flag options were limited for some reason. I guess I was asking for a declined flag lol.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moderator attention is for the times where community moderation isn't going to cut it. Remember, SO gets thousands of questions per day. Community moderation is a key tool in allowing the high level moderation to happen without overwhelming them.

Triage does contain the poorly named **Unsalvageable** button. You can opt to vote for closure of the thread from there. I know you can't see it anymore, but it already had 4 close votes (3 for Too Broad, which this is). Closing the thread would have been the best course of action here. In your case (not enough rep to cast a Close vote) I would **Skip**. One tip I have for moderation queues is, when in doubt, open the question in a new tab and look at it there. Sometimes you can see more information that will help you decide (like close votes, which you could see).

Also remember that casting downvotes does help. A highly downvoted question is more likely to be moderated by other users.

Comment: I understand, but it didn't gave me the other options when clicking the Unsalvageable button. I only had the Moderator's Attention flag available. I also don't have enough rep to cast close votes :P.

Comment: @JohnOdom Yeah, I thought 250 was the level for casting Close votes. It's actually 3k